# How to i use a eventlistener function

Tags: javascript

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at <anonymous> (localhost꞉8080/script.js:4:17)
```

I try running a website and getting error:

```
startBtn.addEventListener("click", startTest);
stopBtn.addEventListener("click", stopTest);
```

Answer (score 1):

startBtn and stopBtn should return an element object so that *addEventListener* can be attached to it.From the error it seems that startBtn is returning null and the *addEventListener* cannot be attached to a null value.

**HTML:**

```html
<button id="startBtn">Start</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```js
document.getElementById("startBtn").addEventListener("click", startTest);
```